# Arranging a picture in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to figure out (like in Microsoft Word) in Visual Studio 2010, how to "arrange" a picture box to "Send it to the back" of the form? I would like to put buttons on the image below on top of the image shown below. At present, the picture is covering the buttons. Is there a way to do this?

Hopefully that's clear enough to understand.

Thanks!

[image: the card]

[image]

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF?

Comment: Just normal Windows Forms? Sorry.. I'm a newbie I'm not sure I know the difference.

Comment: @bexolo the difference is winforms is old and clunky and useless and WPF is current, shiny, beautiful, scalable, resolution independent, MVVM-able, animatable, simply better.

Comment: I haven't really used WPF much. In general (though there are certainly exceptions) I find new versions of things that totally change everything, that people go all crazy about for no other reason than they're "current", are just more of a pain :p. WPF might well be great, but while winforms is old, I wouldn't really call it "useless". And only occasionally clunky, for what it was designed for (namely, win forms).

Comment: Do form elements not have a z-index to control?

Comment: @C.Lang I believe under the hood, in the designer, reordering controls just reorders the order in which the controls are Add()-ed to their parent (in this case the form itself). You *could* go into the designer and reorder them yourself, but most of the time you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your buttons, right click on one, click "Bring to Front". (Or, at this point equivalently, right click your picture box, click "Send to back".)